# Is it mandatory to follow an Imam?

Tags: fiqh, hadith-interpretation, politics

I have some question based on the following hadith from [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/90):

> One who withdraws his band from obedience (to the Amir) will find no
>   argument (in his defence) when he stands before Allah on the Day of
>   Judgment, and one who dies without having bound himself by an oath of
>   allegiance (to an Amir) will die the death of one belonging to the
>   days of Jahillyya.

Based on this:

1. Is it obligatory for every muslim to follow an Imam ?
2. How to know who to consider as imam ?
3. Does the four mujtahid (Imam Abu Hanifa RA, Imam Malik RA, Imam Shafii RA and Imam Ahmad Ibn Hanbal) says anything about the above questions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to follow a particular madhab?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36257/is-it-necessary-to-follow-a-particular-madhab)

Comment: No no, it's not about madhab at all here, while I am living, should I have an Islamic leader who I follow, that's my question

Comment: @Ahmed The hadith is about leadership (caliph or al-Imamah al-Kubra) not following a scholar. The word Imam in the question title is clearly misleading here!